# Installing VirtualBox guest additions on v4.3.28 (IE no Devices menu tab)?

Tags: virtualbox

Using OSX Yosemite and VirtualBox v4.3.28 I'm trying to install guest additions. In all online sources it says go to Devices -> Install Guest Additions but in this version I guess there is no Devices menu. In all the screenshots on the help it shows Devices next to Window and that is just not present on my VB (See screenshot). I've checked in other menus and VB preferences but I don't see anything related to guest additions or devices anywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll only get that menu once you start the Virtual Machine, which launches in a separate application in the Dock. That Virtual Machine application has a devices menu, or you can right click on the CD icon in the status bar.

Comment: Check. Thanks. I was trying to get everything setup before I launched the VM.

Answer (score 2):

I'll leave this info here if someone has the same problem as me:

To reveal the Devices menu in the guest machine:

1. Go to the Virtual Box manager and select the machine you are having problems with.
2. Click on **Settings > User Interface**  then make sure the "Devices" button is selected.

Doing this revealed the Devices menu in my guest box.

Comment: Wow. Some update to VBOX must have unselected those options. Very confusing. Why on earth would someone want to unselect those options? Thankyou for solving this!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with MAC host and ubuntu guest. Finally, I found this,

1. Go to preferences.
2. Select "input"->"Virtual Machine"
   Add shortcut key to "Menu Bar Settings" (I added HOST key + M)
   [image]

3.Click "OK" and go to running virtual machine and press the key combination for Menu Bar Settings. Then you can see menu on top of the screen
[image]

Comment: I'm guessing this was copied from somewhere? (based on the fact "0 down vote" is what appears if you start selecting at the 0 vote indicator instead of the top of an answer) Would you care to credit your source?

Comment: @tubedogg, Thanks for the comment. I have published this  another forum and copied from there. Sorry for that. I removed "0 down vote".